# preg_replace causing dollar signs get removed

Tags: php, regex, string, cakephp, preg-replace

I have an email system, where user write a message and it will send the message.
The main problem which I just found, consider this code

```
    $findEmail = $this->Data->field('body', array('id' => 1610));

    //$getUserEmailTemplate will take frm dbase and e.g: 
    //Hi, @@MESSAGE@@. From: StackOverflow
    //It should change @@MESSAGE@@ part to data from $findEmail (in this example is the $74.97 ...)

    $getUserEmailTemplate = $findUser['User']['email_template'];
    $emailMessage = preg_replace('/\B@@MESSAGE@@\B/u', $findEmail, $getUserEmailTemplate);

    debug($findEmail);
    debug($emailMessage);
```

and consider this input for the email for $findemail result:

```
$74.97
$735.00s
```

$email Message will result in:

```
.97
5.00s
```

How can I fix this? I feel like there's problem with my preg_replace pattern.

User template can be anything, as long as there is @@MESSAGE@@ which, that part will be changed to the user message input.

Thank you

Answer (score 13):

Pre-parse the replacement text to escape the `$` when followed by a number (remember that `$n` has special meaning when using in the replacement text). See the [comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#103985) on the php.net docs page:

> If there's a chance your replacement text contains any strings such as
> "$0.95", you'll need to escape those $n backreferences:

```
<?php
  function escape_backreference($x){
    return preg_replace('/\$(\d)/', '\\\$$1', $x);
  }
?>
```

Comment: @djot: [Don't think so?](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f81db648bffbb7e658de2d8c0ea47fef59a685af) (and the [sanitized version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c666c40dfd7de78b5431fff1f3b253cdf51cbe89))

Comment: Ok. So `preg_replace` kills the `$`.

Comment: It does not kill _all_ `$`'s, Only `$`'s followed by a number between 0 - 99 (the maximum number of backreferences), as there is no such subpattern it substitutes an empty string for those. A simple `addcslashes($replacestring,'$');` will take care of it.

Comment: Ah well, you _can_, it could be overkill though. `\$` not followed by a number in the replace will also be `$` in the result, so, `addcslashes` works fine, with possibly less overhead then the replace function provided (although it is technically a more _correct_ solution). My main reason for commenting was on djot's remark, I've no objection to the current answer, I voted for it.

Comment: @Wrikken: I didn't mean to come across abrasive, my apologies. To alleviate further confusion, though, I'd changed the semantics to be a tad more explicit. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The high-voted function `escape_backreference` is incomplete in the general case: it will only escape backreferences of the form `$n`, but not those of the form `${n}` or `\n`.

To escape any potential backreferences, change

```
    $emailMessage = preg_replace('/\B@@MESSAGE@@\B/u', $findEmail, $getUserEmailTemplate);
```

to

```
    $emailMessage = preg_replace('/\B@@MESSAGE@@\B/u', addcslashes($findEmail, '\\$'), $getUserEmailTemplate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reason:

The `$1` portion of a replacement text stands for the first group/match found. So if you have `abc 123` and you try `preg_match('/([\w]+)-([\d]+)/')`, regex will store internally something like `$1 = abc` and `$2 = 123`. Those variables are going to exists, even if they have no value.

So, for example:

```
$text = '[shortcode]';
$replacement = ' some $var $101 text';
$result = preg_replace('/\[shortcode\]/', $var, $text);
// returns "some $var 1 text"
```

As the match group `$10` is empty is going to be replaced by a null string.

That's why you need to scape any `$NN` from your REPLACEMENT text before running the `preg_replace` function.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

If (ever) an template hast been in `$getUserEmailTemplate`, you did overwrite (destroy) it with this line;

```
$getUserEmailTemplate = "@@MESSAGE@@";
```

So just remove this line and make sure, `$getUserEmailTemplate` really contains anything and best of all a template.

Comment: And perhaps you'd better use `str_replace()` here ;)

Comment: Please check my edited description. That's how the template get the data

Comment: Seems like using str_replace fix the problem. I will test some more. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Guess your template just includes "pure" PHP and tries to use $74 as variable, which does not exist and does not hold any data. So change the quotes in the template to single quotes `'`.

guessed template:

```
$tpl = "Sum: $74.97"; //results in "Sum: .97"
```

corrected template:

```
$tpl = 'Sum: $74.97'; //results in "Sum: $74.97"
```

Comment: it's not solving the problem when I tried it. from my code, I change it to smtg like $getUserEmailTemplate = '@@MESSAGE@@'; It still cause the same problem.

Comment: Your code is somehow incorrect, because you don't even have a template. Also you replace message with message by email, which is dollars ;) ???