# preg_replace is modifying JavaScript

Tags: php, regex

I have a template tool, that replaces placeholders one of the pieces of the tool loads other files, here is what I am using for debugging:

```
var_dump($string);
$tmp = preg_replace('/\\$import\(("|\')' . $f . '("|\')\).*;/i', $string, $tmp);
var_dump($tmp);
```

The first `var_dump` prints out the contents of a file, and in the file there is this line of JavaScript:

```
$("#image-menu .info").html(text.replace(/(.+?:)/, "<b>$1</b>"));
```

After the `pre_replace` I have the second `var_dump` which then prints out this:

```
$("#image-menu .info").html(text.replace(/(.+?:)/, "<b>"</b>"));
```

As you can see `$1` was replaced by a `"`, and I am not sure why. Any ideas as to why it is getting replaced?

Here is the full method:

```
private function loadIncludes(){
    $tmp     = $this->template;
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all('/(\\$import\(("|\')(.+?)("|\')\).*;)/i', $tmp, $matches);
    $files   = $matches[3];
    $replace = 0;
    foreach($files as $key => $file){
        $command = preg_replace("/\\\$import\((\"|').+?(\"|')\)/", "", $matches[0][$key]);
        $string  = $this->import($file);
        $string  = $this->runFunctions($string, "blah" . $command);
        $f       = preg_quote($file, "/");
        var_dump($string);
        $tmp     = preg_replace('/\\$import\(("|\')' . $f . '("|\')\).*;/i', $string, $tmp);
        var_dump($tmp);
        $replace++;
    }
    $this->template = $tmp;
    if($replace > 0){
        $this->loadIncludes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using regex to modify your code?

Comment: It isn't supposed to modify the code, It is just supposed to load a file as a string and append it to the current string.

Comment: You have to escape the `$` sign.

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg\_replace causing dollar signs get removed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993863/preg-replace-causing-dollar-signs-get-removed)

Answer (score 0):

Within single quotes you can't use control characters like `\r` or `\n`, meaning you don't have to double-escape your `$`. Your `\\$` can simply be `\$`.