# php regex prevent replacing $ symbol

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a php function which generates tags from string:

```
function generate_tags($text)
{
    $string = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', ' ', $text);
    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
    $string = mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8');
    $keywords = explode(' ', trim($string));
    foreach($keywords as $key => $value)
    {
        if((strlen($value)) < 1)
        {
            unset($keywords[$key]);
            continue;
        }
    }
    $result = array_unique($keywords);
    $result = array_values($result);
    return $result;
}
```

The string is:
**Ke$ha - We Are Who We Are (Cherry Cole Private Booty) Full Oficial Version**

But it replaces $ symbol. How can I prevent $ symbol on my function?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/767714/5620297) may be of use. Actually, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18993863/5620297) will probably be more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the first `preg_replace` to skip over `$` as well:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s$]/u', ' ', $text);
```

Comment: @DilaraAliyeva You realize you just have to press the tick underneath the voting buttons. Why have you waited 27 minutes to do that?

Comment: I forgot :/ Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Modify the first preg_replace to skip over $ as well:`$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s$]/u', ' ', $text);`
you just have to press the tick underneath the voting buttons.

Comment: Why did you copy the previous answer?